# How to submit form if validate using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I am validating form with jquery. So when form submit i am using `event.preventDefault();` after validate form , form will be submit to respective action page.But in my case it doesn't work.

Code what i did-

```
$('form[name=contact_form]').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('form[name=contact_form]').serialize();
        var phone = $.trim($('form[name=contact_form]').find('input[name=PHONE]').val()).length;
        var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
        var alert = $('#contact_alert');
        var success = $('#contact_success');
        if(phone==0){
            phone.focus();
            alert.html("<p class='alert alert-danger' style='text-align:left;'>Phone number is required</p>");
        }
        else if((phone < 10)){
            phone.focus();
             alert.html("<p class='alert alert-danger' style='text-align:left;'>Please enter a valid phone number</p>");
             return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Html Page :

```
<?php
echo form_open_multipart('home/inquiry', array('name' => 'contact_form'));
?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="C">
                            <input type="text" name="NAME" id="user-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="PHONE" id="user-phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="user-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="SUBJECT" id="user-subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Reason for inquiry"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="MESSAGE" id="user-message"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-warning">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not call `event.preventDefault();` if you want the form to be submitted after it validates ok.

Returning false after failed validation is enough.

Comment: if i don't call `event.preventDefault();` then this function `$('form[name=contact_form]').submit(function(event) ` is not calling form directly submit..

Comment: It looks like there should be `return false` in `if (phone==0)` part too. You are returning `false` when phone is shorter than 10 chars, but not when it has length equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).submit();
```

When it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `return true;` for `$(this).submit();`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like

```
$("#submit").submit(function(e){
    if(validateFields() == true){ //If all fields are valid
        $("#submit").submit();
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault(e);
    }    
});
```